# What does "go with huge to block" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, jokes

A dialogue from *[3000 Miles to Graceland](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M17072247f/3000+Miles+to+Graceland/Do+you+like+women+with+large+breasts%3F)* (2001):

> - Man 1: Do you like women with large breasts? Or women with huge breasts?
> - Man 2: I'm going to go with huge to block.

Is this some kind of joke?

Comment: Where is this from? A game show? Or just a conversation?

Comment: Its' from from 3000 Miles to Graceland

Comment: This might be a visual joke, I've not seen the movie, and I cannot make head or tails of the punchline. I'll leave it to others to decipher.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an allusion to grid-based quiz shows like Hollywood Squares, in which contestants 'capture' cells in the grid by answering questions correctly. Capturing a line of cells is required to win, so if one contestant is on the verge of establishing a winning line, their opponent may elect to play for a 'block' — attempt to capture a square which will interrupt the line.

Without more context it's impossible to say why Man 2 answers with this joke. It may be meant to indicate the silliness of the question; or it may be just smart-ass crosstalk in keeping with the question.

Comment: This is just a casual shred of conversation. Two police investigators exchange these lines while one is looking intently at a map. The other is probably feeling a bit bored. They are investigating a criminal case. Great answer, Stoney. I wondered so much about the question that I got hold of the movie.

Comment: I’ve not seen the movie either, but this was my first inclination, too; I think it’s a vague reference to the old _Hollywood Squares_ show. Because Paul Lynde occupied the center square, [“Paul Lynde to block”](https://www.google.com/#q=%22paul+lynde+to+block%22) became somewhat of a TV trope on its own.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's link provides a bit more of the conversation and context. It would seem that the two guys have noticed the same woman, and that all three are bound for the same destination.

When the second man says "go with huge to block," the woman must have what could be regarded as huge breasts, and the additional phrase "to block" is to indicate that he is "claiming" her. In other words when the two guys get to the destination, then the second guy wants the first chance at flirting with the woman and picking her up.